# How to restore files last opened in Sublime3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I want to automatically open the files I opened last time I used in Sublime 3. I tried all the methods, including setting the `user->preference` tab. I look at the default settings file, and I found there's something strange:

1. the "`hot_exit`" is set to `true`, but it does not work;
2. I couldn't find the "`remember__open_files`" tab. Although I add this in user's preference, it does not work as well.

Could someone tell me how to set this? Thanks!

Comment: Did you cleared temp data in your system?

Comment: How are you quitting Sublime Text? On my Mac, if I hit Cmd-Q, it preserves all of my Sublime windows, and exits the application. Next time I open Sublime, all the windows reappear.

If you have a Mac, make sure you're not closing the windows using the red close buttons in the corners of the windows.